# on Load, all text 1px larger in font-size: then back

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to have all my text within my document.. `<p>` tag, without `<p>` tag, `<span>`, all the h's `h1,h2,h3,h4` etc to bump up by 1 extra pixel in `font-size:` *(from how there are styled in style-sheet)* for just `.5` seconds or `1` second. `+ 1px` then revert back to original layout styled size.

*Note: Also, must have option for a smooth transition.*

Comment: Bump up as in font size?

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 1px, or would a % be sufficient?

Comment: I guess % could work. But i would like to be able to toggle it in similar measures as pixels. EG. Slightly larger, slightly smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to loop around the elements to do this with exactly one pixel:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p').each( function () {
   var $e = $(this);

    var size = parseInt($e.css('font-size'), 10);

    $e.css('font-size', (size + 1) + 'px');

    window.setTimeout(function () {
        $e.css('font-size', size + 'px');
    }, 1000);

    $e.html(size);
});
```

[See this running](http://jsfiddle.net/y0bhzbp8/1/).

It would be a little more efficient to design the page using a relative font size, and then adjust the `body` font by 1px.

You can smooth the transition using:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p  {
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

Warning - if you use this on a great load of text, browsers may struggle to reflow the page smoothly (i.e. it will look more jaggy than just a 1px shift).

Comment: Nice! Anyway to smooth out this transition?

Comment: I have added a CSS transition.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to add a class to the elements you want to change. What we'll do is remove this class after a certain time, then those elements will revert back to their other styles in your css.

Let's say you use this class.

```
.bumped{
  font-size:16px;
}
```

Then you could have some javascript that removes the class after a certain time.

```
var bumpedItems = $('.bumped');
setTimeout(function(){
  bumpedItems.removeClass('bumped');
},1000); //1 second
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using relative units such as `rem` or `em` in order to have more control.

In the example below, all the font sizes are relative to the root element (in this case, `html`).

When the page initially loads, the font is larger and then a class is toggled and the font size transitionally decreases.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('html').addClass('smaller-font');
}, 1000);
```

```css
html { font-size: 17px; }
html.smaller-font { font-size: 16px; transition: 2s font-size; }
h1 { font-size: 1.6rem; }
h2 { font-size: 1.4rem; }
h3 { font-size: 1.2rem; }
p { font-size: 1rem; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>H1 element</h1>
<h2>H2 element</h2>
<h3>H3 element</h3>
<p>Paragraph</p>
```